# Dynamically load control content from PCL View Model

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm, portable-class-library

I have a MVVM project which works fine in WPF. It is basically a TabControl, which dynamically loads its TabItems based on the kind of the selected entity. The TabItem ViewModels are instantiated at runtime (using Activator.CreateInstance), in order to allow the implementation of new tabs over and over without impacting the main project. The full name of the TabItem ViewModel classes are configurable for each kind of Entity.

In WPF, I took the following approach:

Each TabItem ViewModel exposes its ContentTemplate by retrieving it from a resource file:

```
public class CustomEntityPropertyTab : EntityPropertyTabViewModelBase
{
    public override DataTemplate ContentTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            ResourceDictionary dic = new ResourceDictionary();
            dic.Source = new Uri("/CustomProject;component/View/CustomProject.Resources.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            return dic["customEntityPropertyTab"] as DataTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

The main TabControl ViewModel holds an observable collection of EntityPropertyTabViewModelBase - which is bound to the main View as follow:

```
<TabControl Name="EntityPropertyPageTabControl"
            ItemsSource="{Binding EntityPropertyTabs}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPropertyTab}"
            >
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{Binding ContentTemplate}"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

But now, I need this to be available in Silverlight too... So I intended to separate the ViewModel logic in a Portable Class Library, but it doesn't work as PCL doesn't support the DataTemplate property :(
What would then be the best approach to implement dynamic loading of ViewModels shared between WPF and Silverlight UI?

Thanks